# Select the first CSS element using a pseudo class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="myClass">1</div>
<div class="myClass">2</div>
```

How can I select the first element matched by `.myClass`?

I know that I can do: `[PARENT OF .myClass] .myClass:first-child {/* rules */}` but I am curious if there is a pseudo CSS class that selects *the first element matched by the selector*.

Is that possible? How?

The jQuery selector would look like this: `.myClass:first`, but `:first` seems not to work in CSS.

Comment: If there aren't more groups of the same class, and if the first is the first child of a parent, you can use `first-child`, otherwise there is the `nth-child`, which is somewhat more customizable, or the `nth-of-type` selector that isn't supported in all older browsers.

Comment: Given that you have jQuery, why not `$('.myClass:first')` or `$('.myClass').first()` (or other variations thereof)? Or, in plain JavaScript: `document.querySelector('.myClass')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm not sure, but this might work for you.

```
some.great-selector:first-of-type {
  /* Your rules here */
}
```

This will match only first child that matches `some.great-selector` in each parent node. This is somewhat different from what `:first` does in JQuery, but might be still useful, e.g. in conjunction with `parent >` selector.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
.myClass:first-of-type {
      background-color:#233423;
      color:#FFFFFF;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65adr/44/

or you can give a look here for other alternatives:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3psuedoclasses

Answer (score 0):

:first-child is the closest you will get. Though it is well supported if you're looking for something that will work in legacy browsers.

If you want to achieve support in legacy browsers you can apply a style to all elements with a particular class name and then remove it for all sibling classes as so:

```
.my-class {
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.my-class + .my-class {
  border-top: none;
}
```

A rather arbitrary example but you'll get the point.